# Issue using certbot with nginx with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, certbot

I want to create a docker-compose with ngix & certbot services. But when I run it, I always get an error

> Could not select or initialize the requested installer nginx

```
certbot_server | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot_server | 
certbot_server | - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
certbot_server | Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.com.conf
certbot_server | - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
certbot_server | Certificate not yet due for renewal
certbot_server | Could not choose appropriate plugin for updaters: Could not select or initialize the requested installer nginx.
certbot_server | 
certbot_server | - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
certbot_server | The following certificates are not due for renewal yet:
certbot_server |   /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem expires on 2023-10-16 (skipped)
certbot_server | No renewals were attempted.
```

it sees sertificate.

When i run command into certbot container i get error

```
/opt/certbot # certbot renew --quiet --dry-run
Failed to renew certificate domain.com with error: The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed
All simulated renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx_server:
    image: nginx:1.23.2
    container_name: nginx_server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/var/www/server
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    links:
      - server_server

  certbot_server:
    container_name: certbot_server
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 24h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot
```